# How to create Template for email or Message using Python on predefined variables

Tags: python, pandas

I need some help to define template based email or messages where user is defining the message and inserting few predefined variable where python is replacing these variables to actual values.

I have predefined varialbes like: Name, outstandingamount.

User will create templatized messages using these variables:
Example: Hi {{Name}}, You have {{outstandingamount}}, please send us at your earliest convinced.

So what is the best way to replace the {{Name}} to actual value of Name when sending these messages.

Just want to get some idea from group what's the best way to make this happen.  Or if there is any Python library that can help to achieve this task.

Really appreciate your help and consideration.

Comment: There are MANY Python template libraries, because that's a very common need in web apps.  The simplest is just to use the built-in f-strings:  `f"Hi, {name}!  You have an outstanding balance of {outstandingamount}."`

Comment: Thanks Tim for your prompt response. Its good suggest to use f-string however my question that I am allowing end-user to define their own messages where they can create their own message using pre-defined variable.  In that case how can I wrap this message in f-string.  Thank you.

Comment: The string `.format()` tool has the same capabilities.  You can pass keyword arguments for the values to be substituted.  `"Hi, {name}!  You have an outstanding balance of {outstandingamount}.".format( name="George", outstandingamount=123.45)`.  You can use the `**kwargs` syntax to pass a dictionary there.

Comment: You can use jinja2 too

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo.  I am using Jinja for this purpose now and it works like Charm!